# Zoom failed to detect my speaker

Tags: audio, zoom-meeting

When I join a Zoom call I'm getting the message "failed to detect your speaker". This is only in Zoom, it's working fine in Teams and Google Meet. On my Windows laptop I've tried -

Testing the speaker - it is listed but I can't hear the test sound. There is no output level. Microphone is OK, during the test I can see the input level moving.
Uninstalling and re-installing zoom
Trouble shooting sound problems (no problem detected)
Allowing access to microphone (microphone is working fine)

Anyone know what else it could be?